# New Realm migration gets called on new app installs

Tags: ios, swift, realm, database-migration, realm-migration

I have an app which uses `Realm`, it currently has two different migrations and I'm working on the third one, but for some reason this new migration is having a weird behavior. The way I understand migrations is that the new ones will only run if previous schema version already exists otherwise they will be ignored and the schema will be created base on the model's structure.

Here is what I'm seeing.

#### Scenario 1: WORKS FINE.

If the app was previously installed, everything works fine, the new migration 3 runs and it does everything it supposed to do, data gets converted successfully and everything works fine as expected.

#### Scenario 2: ERROR.

If the app is being installed for the first time and the user starts adding data as soon as the app launches, the app will crash the next time the app is launched (the second time AppDelegate is called). I put a print statement and it looks like the migration 3 runs the second time the app is launched but not in the first launched.

#### Scenario 3: WORKS FINE after hack.

If the app is being installed for the first time but this time the user 
doesn't immediately enter any data, instead, he/she kills the app and then restarts the app again, everything works fine, no errors and data can be entered without a problem.

In other words, it looks like migration 3 tries to run the second time the app is launched and it's when the error occurs because the database already has the right schema structure from the first run.

Error Scenario 2:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Any idea why does migration 3 runs on the second launch on new installs? This doesn’t seem like normal behavior, why would it run the second time but not the first time it is launched.

Any thoughts?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            /// Migration 1:
            Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
                schemaVersion: 1,
                migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                    if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                        // configuration for schema 1
                    }
            })        
            /// Migration 2:
            Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
                schemaVersion: 2,
                migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                    if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
                        // configuration for schema 2
                    }
            })
            /// Migration 3:
            Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
                schemaVersion: 3,
                migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                    if (oldSchemaVersion < 3) {
                        // configuration for schema 3
                    }
            })
        }
    }
```

FYI - I have a print in each migration and only migration 3 runs on the second app launch after the app is being installed for the first time.

Comment: I believe you mean the *migration block* runs, not schema. Schema describes the structure of the data and does not run. When the app runs the first time, there isn't a schemaVersion as such, so the default objects will be created based on whatever state they are in. But, because of the code sequence presented in the question, on the first run, the schema version will end up being 3. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Jay - Yes, you're right, I meant to say migration, I have corrected my question. My app is currently released  with the second migration. I'm now adding a third migration to be able to convert `Double` into a  list of doubles `List<Double>` so I'm handling the data conversion in my third migration. I'm only expecting the third migration to run for users who already have the app installed, not for new users, is this assumption correct based the migration code I'm showing above? Thanks

Comment: @Jay - would you mind clarifying the following for me. Based on the migration sequence I’m showing, will migration 3 run for new users? My intent is to run migration 3 for existing users who already have schema 1 or 2 but not for new users.

Comment: No, no migration will happen since the realm didn't previously exist for new users. All of the objects will be fresh with nothing to migrate - see my first comment. However, the schema version will be set to 3. You can test it by adding some print statements within the closures. Delete the existing realm and run it.

Comment: I’m ok with that, what it’s weird is that migration 3 runs for new users on the second time the AppDelegate is called, any idea?

Comment: The actual migration within Migration 3 cannot run if the schema version is 3 due to `oldSchemaVersion < 3`. That tells me there's something else going on outside the code in your question as the only way it could run is if oldSchemaVersion was < 3.

Comment: I just tested it in the simulator. Added a print to all migrations, deleted the app from the simulator, compiled it (no migrations ran at this point), entered some data (data looks good in the Realm browser), closed the app and re-compiled and this time migration 3 ran and the app crashed.

Comment: I read the schema version on the first run by adding a button and reading it with `let fileUrlIs = try schemaVersionAtURL(configCheck.fileURL!)` and I get `version 0` as the initial version, why? It should be version 3 on first installs.

Comment: I attempted to duplicate the issue but your code is working flawlessly. I posted an answer with how I implemented your code. Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will preface this by stating this is being posted as an answer as it attempts to validate that the code in the question is functioning correctly outside of the OP's environment.

I've taken the code and added print statements throughout so the code flow could be easily followed in console.

We start with all files deleted so it would emulate a new install of the app. Your comment says you entered data but that would not be fresh install as the user would not have any data yet.

Here's duplicate code with some print statements added. For me, this is a macOS app, but an iOS app will behave the same.

The migration function is located in the AppDelegate and called like this

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        self.doMigrate()
```

and then the function

```
func doMigrate() {

    print("starting schema version: \(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.schemaVersion)")

    /// Migration 1:
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            print("migration 1")
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                print(" old schema < 1, performaing migration")
                // configuration for schema 1
            }
    })

    print("schema is now: \(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.schemaVersion)")

    /// Migration 2:
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 2,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            print("migration 2")
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
                print(" old schema < 2, performaing migration")
                // configuration for schema 2
            }
    })

    print("schema is now: \(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.schemaVersion)")

    /// Migration 3:
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 3,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            print("migration 3")
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 3) {
                print(" old schema < 3, performaing migration")
                // configuration for schema 3
            }
    })

    print("schema is now: \(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.schemaVersion)")
}
```

On first run, here's the output, noting no migration happens

```
starting schema version: 0
schema is now: 1
schema is now: 2
schema is now: 3
```

When the code is run a second time, the output is identical

```
starting schema version: 0
schema is now: 1
schema is now: 2
schema is now: 3
```

Even if I add or change the models, add or change data, the output remains the same - with the exception of it does crash because it needs a migration if an object property is removed.

So the answer is: If you're not seeing the same behavior, there's something else affecting the code/realm structure in your environment. This works the same way whether it's run once or 3 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot for following along. Even though this is not a straight answer, I will mark it as the right answer since it is pointing me in the right direction. As you have mentioned it before this may have to do with something else I'm doing in my app, I will dig into it. Thanks a lot for verifying my code.

Comment: @fs_tigre Cool. Please keep me in the loop and feel free to update/edit my answer once you discover what's actually causing the issue.

Comment: @ Jay -  I have found what is triggering the call to migration 3 in the second run. In the first `ViewController` of my app I’m reading all `realm` objects in the `ViewDidLoad` method which is what is triggers it. What I don’t quite understand is, how can this trigger a block which is inside the `AppDelegate` class. In fact, after the first run, I can trigger migration 3 block even from a tap of a button at any time, which doesn’t make sense to me, how is it possible to call a migration block which is inside `AppDelegate` with a tap of a button? Query for reading: `realm.objects(Item.self)`

Comment: @fs_tigre Is this a macOS app or iOS?

Comment: It's an iOS app. Thanks.

Comment: @fs_tigre So accessing Realm from for the first time from anywhere in your code will fire the migration block, regardless of where it is. In other words, if you remove the access to realm from viewDidLoad and put it in a button, the migration code will not execute. As soon as you click that button, *then* the migration will fire. That's the thing about closures - they run asynchronously and can 'activate' at a later time. What I do, in my app delegate, right after the migrations are set up is add a 'fake' call to realm to get those to fire `let _ = try! Realm() //will fire the migration`

Comment: @ Jay FYI - After more research, I found out that the real problem was caused by a `Realm` object I was saving right before the migrations. I moved that code to be after all of the migrations and it completely solved my issue. Thank you very much for the good information about closures and how you implement your migrations.